# Feedback base on cell value

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Example]

How do I carry out the function? I'm sure this is beyond nested if.

- Feedback base on value in column G,J & M.
- Value to compare with number text in red.
- Feedback generated in column N for MX-IE21001-1, MX-IE21001-2 & MX-IE21001-3 which have exceeded the range, in red text.
- Given the scenario when MX-IE21001-3 cumulative settlement value is -50, MX-IE21001-2 value is -8 & MX-IE21001-1 value is -2. Column N will automate"Exceeded PDL @ MX-IE21001-3 & Exceeded AL @ MX-IE21001-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a set of nested ifs concatenated together. The test for MX-IE21001-1 would look something like this:

```
= IF(N13<$G$19,"Exceeded PDL @ MX-IE21001-1",
     IF(N13<$F$19,"Exceeded AL @ MX-IE21001-1",""))
```

Let's call that `Test1`. You can do the other two tests, `Test2` and `Test3`, analogously.

Then you can string them together like so

```
= Test3 & " " & Test2 & " " & Test1
```